# How to get the element of uiscrollView which is at scrollIndicator

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I want to get the element which it is at the scrollIndicator when the user scrolls.
So, to be more clear, when the user scrolls, I want to get the element which is being dragged ( which is at the scoll indicator).

my scrollview is horizontal.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Try using `UIScrollView's` `scrollIndicatorInsets` which returns a `UIEdgeInsets`.

Comment: yes I . tried it but it always return a static value (always (0,0,0,0))

Comment: Are you asking how to get a reference to the actual `scrollIndicator` object?

Comment: I'm asking how to get the object which is scrolled horizontally.
So I give you example :
I have 6  imagesViews to be scrolled.
I want to  know if i scroll to image index 3 then I want to get this position : get the index of which element we are now  during scrolling 
I hope to be clear thank you

Comment: @Moez - OK... you need to elaborate a bit more. Suppose the user scrolls to the point where the right-half of one image is visible and the left-half of the next image  is visible? Which "index" would you want to get? Do you have paging enabled, so the scrollView snaps to a "full image" position?

Comment: @DonMag No my scrollView has not paging enabled.
But to asnwer your question, It is ok i can check the less index : if the scroll between two images , I choose the first one .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, all your scrollView subviews will be the same size, and they will each be the size of the scrollView's frame.

Using that assumption, the basic idea is to get the scrollView's `contentOffset`, divide it by the width of the scrollView, and convert it to an `Int` to give you the "index" of which subview is showing.

So, if your scrollView is 100-pts wide, each image view you add will be 100-pts wide. If the user has scrolled so the `contentOffset` is `20` (scrolled just a little to the left), the index will be:

```
    Int(20.0 / 100.0)  // equals 0
```

If the user has scrolled just past the end of the 3rd image, the `contentOffset` will be (for example) `315`, and the index will be:

```
    Int(315.0 / 100.0)  // equals 3
```

*(using standard Zero-based indexing, of course)*

Here is a *basic* example - all elements added in code, so just use an empty ViewController in Storyboard and assign it this class:

```
class ScrollIndexViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    var theScrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let v = UIScrollView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return v
    }()

    // array of colors for imageView backgrounds
    // could be array of images (or image names), for example
    var colors: [UIColor] = [
        .red,
        .green,
        .blue,
        .orange,
        .magenta,
        .yellow,
        .brown,
        .cyan,
        .purple,
    ]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // add the scroll view
        view.addSubview(theScrollView)

        // constrain it to the full view
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            theScrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            theScrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            theScrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            theScrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            ])

        // set scroll view delegate to self
        theScrollView.delegate = self

        // var to use when constraining the scrollable subviews
        var prevImageView: UIImageView?

        // for each element in the array
        for cl in colors {

            // create a new image view
            let v = UIImageView()
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            v.backgroundColor = cl

            // add it to the scroll view
            theScrollView.addSubview(v)

            // all added image views get
            //      width = scroll view width
            //      height = scroll view height
            //      top = scroll view top
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                v.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theScrollView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1.0),
                v.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theScrollView.heightAnchor, multiplier: 1.0),
                v.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theScrollView.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
                ])

            // if this is the first added image view,
            // constrain leading to scroll view leading
            if cl == colors.first {
                NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                    v.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theScrollView.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
                    ])
            }

            // if this is the last added image view,
            // constrain trailing to scroll view trailing
            if cl == colors.last {
                NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                    v.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theScrollView.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
                    ])
            }

            // if prevImageView is not nil, that means we've added
            // an image view before this one, so,
            // constrain leading to trailing of previous image view
            if let pv = prevImageView {
                NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                    v.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pv.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
                    ])
            }

            // set prevImageView to this image view
            prevImageView = v

        }

    }

    func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        // if user scrolled by swiping

        // calculate the "index" of the visible image view
        let idx = getImageIndex(scrollView)
        // do what you want with the index
        print(#function, "Index: \(idx)")

    }

    func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {

        // if user scrolls and stops (i.e. doesn't swipe and lift)
        if !decelerate {
            // calculate the "index" of the visible image view
            let idx = getImageIndex(scrollView)
            // do what you want with the index
            print(#function, "Index: \(idx)")
        }

    }

    func getImageIndex(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) -> Int {

        // get the contentOffset
        let offX = scrollView.contentOffset.x

        // get the width of the scroll view
        // (which is also the width of the image view subviews)
        let svW = scrollView.frame.width

        // return offset.x / image view width as an Int
        return Int(offX / svW)

    }

}
```

Keep in mind --- if the user scrolls to the left until only a single pixel width of an image is visible at the left edge, ***that image*** will still be considered the "visible image view".

You might want to change the index calculation to return the "most visible" subview, which you could do with:

```
    return Int((offX / svW).rounded())
```

Or perhaps only if the next image view is at least 75% visible... whatever fits your needs.

Comment: hello @donMag just i want now that the element must be presented to the user with animation?
i used CGAffineTransformMakeScale (1.5,1.5) to show it 
dod you have suggestion to this ?
thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the location when user starts dragging something you can do that the below way by implementing `willBeginDragging`.

```
extension ViewController : UIScrollViewDelegate {
    func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let location = scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.location(in: scrollView)
        print(location)
    }
}
```

Comment: good Idea but what is the difference if i use the property : scrollview.contentOffset.x ?

Comment: and i want to get the element which is at the scroll indicator (horizontal scrollview)

Comment: please any suggestions ?